# html-coding-how do i place a text on image in HTML?

Tags: html, image, cordova, text

I am designing this for a phone gap application..i want to code this in html..

i have two questions..

**Q1)how do i place a text on the image at different positions?**

suc as text1,text2,text3,text4 in the image given here.

**Q2) how to place it at the centre in the page.i had given**

```
   <img src="img/img1.png" style="margin-left:5px;" />
   <img align="middle" />
```

but,this makes no difference.

guidance required.please help.

[image]

**i have another doubt...after running the program....there is the extension part of the body after the footer...if you drag up....you can see thtat the body that is between the header and footer is extended. and it moves evento the right.
any mistake in the coding?**

Comment: You can do it using html5 canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put them in a Div, then give this Div a background style ;)
the code should be like this:

```
<div id='container'> 
 <span> text 1 </span> 
 <span> text 2 </span> 
 <span> text 3 </span>      
 <span> text 4 </span> 
</div>
```

in the css:

```
#container{background:url(path/to/img) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; background-size:100% 100%; display:block; height:...px; width:...px;}
#container span{width:50%; height:25%;display:block; overflow:hidden;float:left;}
```

you can add border to the spans, color etc...

Comment: do you know,how to implement a  SWIPE VIEW using java script (dynamically).in the sense based on the length of a column.1 more doubt can we find the length of specific column? PLEASE REPLY.......ITS....VERY CONFUSING... for me..

Comment: For swipe, Check this link: http://www.awwwards.com/demo/touchSwipe-gallery-demo.html

Comment: T.Baba,thank you, but i have already implemented the Swipe view ...i want something similar to VIEW HOLDER (WHICH WE HAVE IN ANDROID)

Comment: yup use the one in the link i gave it to u before ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by wrapping image with div and z-index. Your code should look like this:

```
<div style="position:fixed; top:10px; left:5px; z-index:250; width:ofimage; height:of image;">
<span style="display:block; width:30; height:20; margins if you need; float:left">text1</span>
 <span style it accordingly and add float left>text2</span><br>
<spanstyle them as first two>text3</span>
<span>text4</span>

</div>

<img src="your image" style="if any">
```